# PHP variable to ajax, using variable inside jQuery function?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a variable with PHP to jQuery where I want to use this variable to append to a specific div.

Here is how I send the variables to jQuery `onclick` : 
`<a onclick="searchEmail('<?php echo $location ?>');">`

Then I begin the jQuery function like this:
`function searchEmail(location) {`

This how the ajax part in the function looks like, and it works perfectly, but I want to use the `location` variable for this part of the code: `$(location).appendTo('#test');` so that I append the text in `location` to a specific `<p` with ID `#test`.

```
function searchEmail(email,title,content,location,siteurl) {
  $(document).off("click", "#confirm").on("click", "#confirm", function (event) {
    var $url = (admin_ajax.url);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $url,
      datatype: "html",
      data: { 'action': 'search_notify_email', email: email, title: title, content: content, location: location, siteurl: siteurl },
      success: function() {
        searchNotification();
        console.log( location );
        $('<p>'+location+'</p>').appendTo('#test');
      },error:function() {
        searchNotificationError();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: If location is not a jQuery object, you can not append that to that div. You need to wrap it first, or change the append method with html method.

Comment: How is the wrap done?

Comment: Just; replace `$(location)` to `$('<div>'+location+'</div>')`.

Comment: Tried that, but still nothing is displayed, I tried `$('<p>Text</p>')` to make sure it worked first. And then `$('<p>'+location+'</p>')` and I know location contains data. But do I need to declare it some other way to be able to use it in `success`

Comment: Can you check location value like console.log(location)?

Comment: Please complete your function with writing the all function so we can see the all story. You are passing location to your searchEmail function and calling that ajax in it right? So definitely location must have a value.

Comment: Yes, exacly, I pass `location` to `searchEmail` and later pass location to a PHP function called `search_notify_email` where I make it a PHP variable `$location = $_POST['location'];` and I get this sent in an email. And there the variable is not empty. I cannot add much more info to the first post.

Comment: Updated with the complete jQuery function

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a variable in your jQuery code to store the location:

```
var location = '<?php echo $location; ?>';

$(document).off("click", "#confirm").on("click", "#confirm", function (event) {
var $url = (admin_ajax.url);
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: $url,
  datatype: "html",
  data: { 'action': 'search_notify_email', location: location },
  success: function() {
    searchNotification();
    $(location).appendTo('#test'); /* or $('#test').append(location); */
  },error:function() {
    searchNotificationError();
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: You should also escape the location variable: [escape a php sting for a javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

Answer (score 1):

> so that I append the text in location to a specific

If you've just text then you need instead of appending the `text()` method :

```
$('#test').text(location); //Note it will replace the original text
```

Or:

```
var p = $('#test');
p.text(p.text() + location);
```

Comment: Mind that, this is not appending. This is replacing.

Comment: Tried that, but it doesn't display anything at all. I know there is data in `location`, is there anything I am missing?

Comment: @jockebq try `console.log( location );` just before the answer's line.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki that comes up empty, I see it in the console log but it is just an empty line. Which is weird because the ajax part of this is working fine, and the location is transfered.